# Formatted EFI partition of Windows 10 using Live Ubuntu, how to fix it now?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, uefi

Call me stupid, but I just formatted the EFI system partiton on Windows 10, while using GPARTED on Ubuntu. Now Windows 10 will not boot. How can I repair the EFI system partition so that Windows 10 will boot properly?
I want to avoid Ubuntu or any linux live cd from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Create lost/deleted EFI partition by boot into CMD :

- Boot with Windows 10/8/7 installation media > press SHFIT + F10 on the first screen to bring up Command Prompt
- Run the following commands :

  ```
  diskpart
  list disk
  select disk number   (enter the number of the disk where resided the EFI partition - normally 0)
  list partition
  create partition efi
  format quick fs=fat32
  list partition
  list volume       (note the volume letter where Windows is installed)
  exit              (leave diskpart)
  bcdboot X:\windows (X is the volume letter of the Windows partition)
  ```

BCDBoot copies the boot files from the Windows partition to the EFI System partition and creates the BCD store in the same partition.

Now you can remove the Windows installation media and restart the computer.

For more information with screenshots see [this article](https://www.partition-tool.com/resource/partition-recovery/restore-repair-deleted-efi-boot-partition-in-windows-10-8-7.html).